# Xml Parser in C#

Tags: c#

I want to change the value under key by matching the name attribute
for example, 
If the name attribute under key is ankit then the respective value should be changed from "no" to "yes"
I want to code in C sharp,please help me
Sample Code :

```
<abc>
    <setting name="NameSettings">
        <key name="ankit" value="no">
        <key name="rohan" value="Y"/>
        <key name="anoop" value="1"/>
    </setting>
</abc>
```

Comment: Please, Don't demoralize new user like this. Help him to get out of his problem as per my opinion.

Comment: @Sikender, His question is very "googleable"...

Comment: @Sikender: This has nothing to do with demoralizing new users. It has to do with teaching new users how to use our site, how he should try to help himself, before posting here.

Comment: @Mitch : Am new to programming. Am just able to display all attributes , not able to proceed further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var key = doc
            .Descendants("setting")
            .Descendants("key")
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "ankit");
        if (key != null)
        {
            key.Attribute("value").Value = "yes";
        }
        doc.Save("new.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me.. Am totally new to C# and programming stuff.. I tried executing ur code.. It says "XDocument" does not exist in this context. What is the use of XDocument..Can you please explain me

Comment: @moni : where is your above code which you mention in question? put that xml sample code in text.xml file and then try it. and also you need to add related "system.xml.linq" namespace.

Comment: @Sikender :class Program 
{ 
    static void Main() 
    { 
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml"); 
        var key = doc 
            .Descendants("setting") 
            .Descendants("key") 
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "ankit"); 
        if (key != null) 
        { 
            key.Attribute("value").Value = "yes"; 
        } 
        doc.Save("new.xml"); 
    } 
}

Comment: no not this code. your xml "<abc>
    <setting name="NameSettings">
        <key name="ankit" value="no">
        <key name="rohan" value="Y"/>
        <key name="anoop" value="1"/>
    </setting>
</abc>"

Comment: @Sikender : where should the location of the xml file should be ?its throwing an error "The 'key' start tag on line 3 position 10 does not match the end tag of 'setting'. Line 6, position 7."

Comment: @Sikender : I tried giving the full path of the xml file and I also tried placing the xml file in bin/Debug

Comment: It says the exception was unhandled ..Please help me

Comment: @moni, That's because your XML isn't well-formed! Please use search to find answers to your trivial questions.